# There are four promotional unlocks in Borderlands 2. What are they?

Tags: borderlands-2

The title pretty much says it all. There is a hack going around to unlock all **four** of the promotional unlocks. I was wondering what exactly they are? For example, in my game UnlockId=2 is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These aren't necessarily in order of how they appear in the ini file, but they're what I got when I edited the file to unlock all of the bonuses.

1. The Creature Dome from Gamestop.
2. Premiere Club(all preorders) - I presume for the purposes of this file, it's just the Gearbox Guns and Vault Hunter relic and not the free character DLC and golden key.
3. A special grenade mod(not sure what the source of this is)
4. Special character skins(Collectors Edition unlock)

Comment: Some character skins are unlocked when the game detects a Borderlands 1 save file, could that be their source?

Comment: @Adeese I received those before I edited the ini file, so I doubt it.