# How do I unlock all of the promotional content?

Tags: borderlands-2

I read [There are four promotional unlocks in Borderlands 2. What are they?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85115/there-are-four-promotional-unlocks-in-borderlands-2-what-are-they) and was wondering if there are (legitimate) ways otherwise to unlock this exclusive content.
I've also been thinking about how the players that I've seen speed-running this game all use a sniper rifle that seems to be rewarded by the Premiere Club promotion. So, being able to unlock that content would help speed-runners who didn't pre-order the game.
I suppose that the answer to this question should include (mention of) [SHiFT codes](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key).

Comment: Apparently, the .ini edit exploit has been patched: http://leviathyn.com/games/news/2012/09/20/randy-pitchford-doesnt-want-you-editing-your-borderlands-2-files/. Thus, use of it would require changing to an older patch.

Comment: Doing something like this is considered piracy (you unlock content you clearly aren't supposed to unlock). Discussing pirating techniques is againt the ToS, so I'm close voting this.

Comment: I will rephrase the question since I've now learned that such content has all been made available for purchase (although, I don't know the grenade mod mentioned in the answer cited),

Answer (score 4):

From [There are four promotional unlocks in Borderlands 2. What are they?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85115/there-are-four-promotional-unlocks-in-borderlands-2-what-are-they):

> 1. The Creature Dome from Gamestop.
> 2. Premiere Club(all preorders) - I presume for the purposes of this file, it's just the Gearbox Guns and Vault Hunter relic and not the
>      free character DLC and golden key.
> 3. A special grenade mod(not sure what the source of this is)
> 4. Special character skins(Collectors Edition unlock)

1. The Creature Slaughterdome has since been made available for purchase.
2. Mechromancer Pack: "In addition to this new class, this pack also includes bonus items which were included in the Borderlands 2 Premiere Club Pack, including the Gearbox Gold Gun Pack, a Golden Key, which unlocks rare items in the mysterious Sanctuary Loot Chest, and the Vault Hunter’s Relic, which boosts your gear-hunting fortunes."
3. [Contraband Sky Rocket](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Contraband_Sky_Rocket)
4. There is a Collector's Edition Pack that can be bought.